# add colors to grunt-js output

Tags: colors, gruntjs, exec, spawn

I've setup grunt to do tdd in windows for my delphi developments.
I have a watch task that runs msbuild and then runs my tests console application (written in delphi).
When I run the test application directly in the windows command prompt it outputs coloured text when grunt does it the colours disappears. I tried running the test task both with exec and spawn but the output using grunt.js is always without colors.
Any Ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

```
opts : {stdio : 'inherit'}
```

to my spawn task fixed the problem